# nagios core issue version 4.3.4 while starting nagios service

Tags: nagios

I am getting error:  Starting nagios:ERROR: Could not create or update '/usr/local/nagios/var/nagios.configtest'   while starting nagios service I have given read/write/exec permission to /usr/local/nagios. Also when I perform config test it is passed successfully.

Comment: I forget meantion some important facts, for example: you OS, how you install Nagios?, atd...

Comment: OS: Ubuntu 14.04. Have installed it with source code. Have followed link: https://support.nagios.com/kb/article/nagios-core-installing-nagios-core-from-source.html#Ubuntu

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ref: [doc-760](https://support.nagios.com/kb/doc-760.html)

> Resolution
>   The resolution to this problem is to remove the /usr/sbin/nologin directive from the passwd file, or to define it as a valid shell. The following examples should resolve the problem (depending on your operating system):
>
> No shell defined:
>
> nagios:x:1001:1001::/home/nagios:
>
> Bash shell defined:
>
> nagios:x:500:500::/home/nagios:/bin/bash
>
> Once you have updated the passwd file you will be able to successfully start the nagios service.

I updated /etc/passwd as specified and nagios started right up.

originally:

```
nagios:x:110:116::/var/lib/nagios:/bin/false
```

now:

```
$ grep nagios /etc/passwd
nagios:x:110:116::/var/lib/nagios:/bin/bash
```

Comment: I understand that this does fix the issue, but does anyone know why the nagios user needs to be able to log in to work?